# Heroku Deployment - Rails 6.1.3 - Bundle install failing - Gemfile.lock platform addition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am trying to deploy a simple Ruby on Rails web app using Heroku. When I attempt to deploy the web app, I get a bundler error saying the correct platform is not within the Gemfile.lock

Here is the build log:

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack

 !     Warning: Multiple default buildpacks reported the ability to handle this app. The first buildpack in the list below will be used.

            Detected buildpacks: Ruby,Node.js

            See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#buildpack-detect-order

-----> Ruby app detected

-----> Installing bundler 2.1.4

-----> Removing BUNDLED WITH version in the Gemfile.lock

-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails

-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-3.0.0

-----> Installing dependencies using bundler 2.1.4

       Running: BUNDLE_WITHOUT='development:test' BUNDLE_PATH=vendor/bundle BUNDLE_BIN=vendor/bundle/bin BUNDLE_DEPLOYMENT=1 bundle install -j4

       Your bundle only supports platforms ["aarch64-linux"] but your local platform is

       x86_64-linux. Add the current platform to the lockfile with `bundle lock

       --add-platform x86_64-linux` and try again.

       Bundler Output: Your bundle only supports platforms ["aarch64-linux"] but your local platform is

       x86_64-linux. Add the current platform to the lockfile with `bundle lock

       --add-platform x86_64-linux` and try again.

 !

 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.

 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.

 !     Push failed
```

I attempted to add the platform to the Gemfile.lock file but was hit with this dependency error:

```
matt@matt-desktop:~/projects/auto-bags$ bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
Resolving dependencies.........
Bundler found conflicting requirements for the Ruby version:
 In Gemfile:
   Ruby (~> 3.0.0.0)

   capybara (>= 3.26) was resolved to 3.35.3, which depends on
     nokogiri (~> 1.8) was resolved to 1.11.1, which depends on
       Ruby (< 3.1.dev, >= 2.5)
```

I have not found a successful fix online. There were some suggestions to remove the Gemfile.lock file but that broke my local server which makes sense. I'll be happy to provide more information if necessary.

Comment: Seem you have error in your ruby versions, please check by changing ruby version to 2.7.2 in your `Gemfile` and install localy same version.

Comment: I guess I do not understand the dependency error message. It appears to suggest I need a ruby version that is >= 2.5 which is satisfied?

Comment: Yes but greater then 2.5 would be 2.7.2 as currently 3.0.0 is not supported by Rails and would be same for Heroku.

Answer (score 1):

running the following command should fix your issue.

```
bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux
bundle install
git add . ; git commit -m fix
```

### Reference

https://www.moncefbelyamani.com/understanding-the-gemfile-lock-file/#platforms

https://bundler.io/man/gemfile.5.html#PLATFORMS

https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/4269#issuecomment-758564690